# Can たり be used in a sentence with only one verb?

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence in the Genki2 textbook (pg. 282):
「時々、隣の人と話したりする。」

I was under the impression that たり is used to list things that you have done/ will do. Is the semantics of たり different in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

たり can be used with just one verb. It just means it's a non-exhaustive list of actions.